# How to get hidden id from particular div

Tags: jquery

I have create Drag-Drop functionality using j - query. Now I am trying to get hidden ids from div. Main div is different and sub div is duplicate.
Please help me. Thanks in advances.

```
<div class="div-A">
   <div class="sub-div">
        <div id="drag-div">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="10" />
        <div>
   <div>
<div>
<div class="div-B">
   <div class="sub-div">
        <div id="drag-div">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="12" />
        <div>
   <div>
<div>
```

If I click on particular  sub-div then it will return me regarding hidden id(11 or 12).

Comment: IDs should be unique. If someone else has the same ID as you, it's considered identity theft.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#sub-div').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('id')
    alert(id);
});
```

`ID` must be unique fix your markup. Use `classes` instead of `ID`

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: yes Id must be unique but this is Drag-Drop code . so these div will be dragged any where and any place

Comment: @user2932185 What it has to do with same id ?

Comment: Also I have change id to div but still its not giving required output.--    <div class="div-A">
   <div class="sub-div">
        <div id="drag-div">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="10" />
        <div>
   <div>
<div>
<div class="div-B">
   <div class="sub-div">
        <div id="drag-div">
                <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID" value="12" />
        <div>
   <div>
<div>

Comment: @user2932185 yeah change all similar id's to classes .Now code becomes `$('.sub-div').click(function () { ... })`

Comment: No, click even is not generated on class. I think its same name so.

Comment: @user2932185 is your site online ?